# Implementing Ruby on website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So as I learn about Ruby I see nothing about using it on a website or how to connect to a database that's not local. Any help is appreciated. I'm learning Ruby for use on the web. Thanks.

Comment: have you installed RoR?

Comment: I Have RubyMine. I'm guessing thats not RoR?

Comment: Change your tag. You have tagged this post as ruby-on-rails.

Comment: Ruby is a programming language and as such can be used for anything. If you want to write a website, language alone would do, but it would take ages before you start writing anything useful, so you have to use some kind of framework. There are two major frameworks for ruby: Ruby on Rails and Sinatra. (RubyMine is an IDE, not a framework.) Sinatra is much simpler, but as you could expect it is much less powerful than rails. Rails on the other hand will take quite a lot of time to learn.

Comment: Thank You. I remember learning php. When I was done everything was being written in mysqli and pdo. I wonder what will change when I'm done with Ruby lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of content on google about deploying and developing a Ruby On Rails website, I would recommend searching Ruby docs, youtube and google.

Here are a few resources that may answer your question:

[Setting up Ruby On Rails Database](http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/15/setting-up-ruby-on-rails-database-connection-using-mysql-on-ubuntu-feisty-fawn/)

[Ruby on Rails Deploy](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy/)

[Rails - Deplying to DigitalOcean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slLsP_Fu-IE)

[Writing web applications with Ruby On Rails](http://12devs.co.uk/articles/writing-a-web-application-with-ruby-on-rails/)

this may also help:

[how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)